# Measuring performance for network Java application

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

We want to automatically measure performance of our Java product.

We want to have following metrics:

- Processor loading
- Memory loading
- Network loading
- Project related metrics

We want to run those performance tests continuously on Jenkins server. Project related performance metrics and system metrics above, will be displayed as some trend graphs.

Could you please suggest a Java performance framework or maybe, approach, to measure system metrics automatically?

I found a [list of open source performance test tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) and considering to use `JMeter` [Java Sampler](https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/creating-a-java-sampler-for-jmeter/) and running it from Java code. But I am not familiar enough with `JMeter` and not sure that this is a proper choice.

Comment: Surely the external server is doing all the real work.  Do you want to measure the client or the server?

Comment: We want to measure our client. It loads processor, memory and network too. Client is also heavy and we want to be aware about it's performance degradation.

Comment: If your client is heavy you should performance tuning it using a profiler like VisualVM, JMC or YourKit.  This will tell you what you need to fix.  Recording metrics continuously will only tell you if you have made a change which dramatically increased the resource consumption.  If your client is more than 10% of the workload you are probably doing something wrong (or it is not just a client)

Comment: You are correct. That exactly what we need: "tell us if we made a change which dramatically increased the resource consumption"

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to time how long it takes to perform an operation which the server plays little or no part.  Ideally your server should be running on the same machine.  If this timing goes up it is likely to mean you used more CPU, or memory, or network overhead.  To find out exactly what changed you are better off using a more precise tool.

Comment: Client is not as heavy as you think :). But this is critical application in other products, so far we want to know about performance degradation. BTW, we are able to measure our client performance with asynchronous requests, but was interested in additional information about VM loading, from there processor, memory and network

Comment: For memory consumption I run a test in a JVM with a low amount of memory. e.g. 64 MB.  If the memory consumption goes up, the test will fail.  The processor consumption should appear in the timing information.  To monitor network consumption you need to record how much data you send, either in the socket layer or in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to use some kind of JMX monitoring / profiling tool, such as VisualVM, https://visualvm.java.net/. It gives detailed processor load, memory load (split by JVM memory pool), and you can extend it to add your own metrics by writing custom MBeans in your code.

I worked on building a monitoring webapp at a previous job - it periodically collected information from servers via JMX, and pinged that information to a Graphite instance so we could track the metrics over long time periods. You could consider doing a similar thing. VisualVM is a good interim solution though.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is a good choice as it's free and open source, it can scale, it is Java-based and can be easily added as a task to CI process.

References:

1. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) - Servers Performance Monitoring reporting CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO
2. There is a [JMeter Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) providing native integration of JMeter tests into continuous build process
3. JMeter tests can be launched as OS command-line task, Ant task, Maven plugin, from Java code and you can use JMeter API to build and execute the test on the fly. See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for details.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like JMeter Jenkins plugin is out of date. I was looking at [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)

Comment: Good catch, I've updated the answer with better link, thanks.